# find out entries not present in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of list of node names and I have a graph with total nodes.

I need to find out nodes names which is not present in list of nodes names.

Ex:

- list of lists of nodes names: `[[x,y,h,j,k],[a,b,c],[t,q,r,v,x,y,k],[a,h,y,q,c]]`
- graph :  all the node names ( need to iterate and find the node names)
       E.g. (node names): `[a,b,c,x,y,h,j,k,t,q,r,v]`
- For the first list `[x,y,h,j,k]` in loop,
  need to return the list of remaining node names present in the graph: `[a,b,c,t,q,r,v]`

It should run in loop for each list inside list of node names.

I am using python and `networkx`. Please help me out

Comment: "What have you tried? What's the specific problem?" (c)

Comment: I tried to iterate over the graph nodes and iterated over the list of list, then checked if list item not found in graph then print the remaining nodes

Comment: I don't see any graphs here, just sets of strings.

Comment: So, what's the problem? This is *a* solution, though a non-optimal one.

Comment: How to iterate over list of lists and check it with the total nodes???

Comment: SO doesn't do your work for you (well, it sometimes does, but this is frowned upon). According to [c53624431](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897590/find-out-entries-not-present-in-a-list/32897864?noredirect=1#comment53624431_32897590), you already have a valid solution (and I can't see what's wrong with it besides it being non-optimal). I suggested a better one, but I'm not writing all the code for you, my job is to push you in the right direction.

Comment: If your solution doesn't work despite looking right, showing the code may allow us to say what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using sets or dicts for efficiency.

```
lists_of_nodes = [['x','y','h','j','k'],['a','b','c'],['t','q','r','v','x','y','k'],['a','h','y','q','c']]
sets_of_nodes = map(set, lists_of_nodes)
all_nodes = reduce(lambda l, r: l.union(r), sets_of_nodes)
complements = [list(all_nodes.difference(node_set)) for node_set in sets_of_nodes]

for complement in complements:
    print complement

'''
['a', 'c', 'b', 'q', 'r', 't', 'v']
['h', 'k', 'j', 'q', 'r', 't', 'v', 'y', 'x']
['a', 'h', 'c', 'b', 'j']
['b', 'k', 'j', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x']
'''
```

Comment: all_nodes = reduce(lambda l, r: l.union(r), sets_of_nodes)

May i know what is happening with this line??

Comment: This is a bit of functional style. Python has a built in function to take union of 2 sets (`A.union(B)`). How would you use this to take a union of more than 2 sets? You could write `buf = {}; for s in sets: buf = buf.union(s)`; `reduce` does the same thing in a more readable way. It takes a function that combines two elements and an iterable, returning the `reduce`ed version.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['x','y','h','j','k'],['a','b','c'],['t','q','r','v','x','y','k'],['a','h','y','q','c']]


def return_remaining(list_of_nodes):
    total = ['a','b','c','x','y','h','j','k','t','q','r','v']
    for node in list_of_nodes:
        if node in total:
            total.remove(node)
    return total

for i in range(len(l)):
    print return_remaining(l[i])
```

Output

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 't', 'q', 'r', 'v']
['x', 'y', 'h', 'j', 'k', 't', 'q', 'r', 'v']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'h', 'j']
['b', 'x', 'j', 'k', 't', 'r', 'v']
```

Comment: N^2 complexity - the list is iterated over for each element.